# Can not print an assigned variable, the console prints the string

Tags: python, string, variables, printing

I am trying to automatize a process.
I need to extract a string and previously assigned it a variable.
For example:

```
H=8
Hello= "Hello"
Hi=(Hello[0])
print(H)
print(Hi)
```

Console prints:

```
8
H
```

and I need the console to print:

```
8
8
```

Comment: `print(H, H)`? The logic is really unclear...

Comment: @mozway They're looking for `eval`, and I refuse :')

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary instead.

Any method that solves this how you want it to be solved will be unsafe and bad practice.

```
data = {'H': 8, 'B': 3}
Hello = "Hello"
Hi = data[Hello[0]]
print(data['H'])
print(Hi)
```

Output:

```
8
8
```

See: [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)